# No Search after Activate flat products / categories

Tags: magento-1.9

i activated the Options "flat products" and "flat categories" to speed up my shop. Now my search function is not working anymore on 1 from 2 store views, i get redirected to home when klicking on a search result.

On the other view, the search function still works...

I already did follow the following steps:

1) Reindex
2) Clean Cache
3) Check the Attributes & Search Options (Still ok because the options did not change)

When i deactivate flat options and reindex, all work fine :(

Please help.
Chris